# Facebook authentication with android app crashed

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

Hi I'm new to Android development and I watched this tutorial [Facebook auth for Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IuLLG2ujCA)

and in my **FacebookActivity.java**

Here's my code:

```
package net.proudcloud.guestlistph;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.model.*;
import com.facebook.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FacebookActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);

        //start facebook login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (state.isOpened()) {

                    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        // callback after Graph API response with user object
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                                welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {


            }


        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is problem ? you didn't mentioned it anywhere

Comment: I wrote the problem on the title. FB authentication for android app crashed

Comment: I mean logcat, errors. what line there is problem ?